# Wordpress is not installing from webbrowser

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu

I have searched a lot, but i can't seem to find the answer to this. I'm setting up a Wordpress website on my VPS but Wordpress isn't loading correctly. I just get this on the homepage of the website :

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

Any idea what could be the problem here? I found it could have something to do with file permissions but i can't find the problem.

(Sorry if this is a noob question)

Comment: This is the index.php file. Means your server is not running/executing PHP

Comment: As above. Are you saying the code above is actually shown in the web browser? If so, then you do not have PHP enabled on your web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install PHP on your webserver, you can do this via the terminal using:

```
apt-get install php5
```

Comment: i'm running php 7, a friend of mine did set it up.  is php 5 better?  (first timer doing this)

Comment: It doesn't sound like it's running at all. Did you personally install PHP7? If so, I'd recommend uninstalling it and putting on version 5, which is more widely used.

Comment: Ye i will do that, "Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress." Is what it's telling me now, i found out that this is a common problem with php 7 so im going to instal 5 now. Thanks for your answer